# MongoDB java driver behaving strangely

Tags: java, mongodb

I have MongoDB as the DB and I am using JAVA driver of MongoDB to connect to the Database. The issue  am facing is quite strange.And it is very premature to comment from my end about any bug in the JAVA driver.

The  issue which I am facing using the driver is that after a few operations in DB, the same code is not performing the operations it is intended to perform. Not Sure why.

See the sample code below

```
MongoClient mongoclient=null;
    DB db;
    DBUtils dbUtils=new DBUtils();
    mongoclient=dbUtils.connectToDB("pingpong");    
    db = mongoclient.getDB("pingpong"); 
    //This is commented out for the time being as data is cleared in postmessage
    //dbUtils.clearData(messageid);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("messageid", new BasicDBObject("$regex",messageid));
    DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("SearchResult");
    DBCursor cursor=coll.find(query);
    int j=1;
    if (cursor.count()>0){
    }else{
        while(j<=5){
            System.out.println("THIS"+messageid);
            BasicDBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("messageid", new BasicDBObject("$regex",messageid));
            DBCollection coll2=db.getCollection("SearchResult");
            DBCursor cursor2=coll2.find(query2);
            if (cursor2.count()>0){
                System.out.println(cursor2.count());
                break;                  
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(j*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            j=j+1;
            if((j==5) ||(j>5)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The foremost issue I am facing is

"BasicDBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("messageid", new BasicDBObject("$regex",messageid));" statement.

Eventhough there is no record in the SearchResult table which matches messagedid, I am getting the whole collections in the record. Say if the messageid is XXXXYYYY. And in the collection there is no record with messageid as XXXXYYYY.

This code executes well for a couple of times. But from the third time, it fetches the whole collection.

I am not sure where I am going wrong or is there an issue in the DRIVER itself.

I am using a 2 member replica set + 1 arbiter setup.

I googled for information, but I am not able to find any info. I believe my code is fine. Is there any kind of stale issue  anyone has face from the driver's point of view.

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Just to add some more info, I  am using the latest java driver version and the latest mongodb version. Also, a friend of mine peer reviewed the code and he is also fine with the code as there is no issue with the logic which is implented. Sometimes, the code works for 10 times flawlessly and then the select query is not working.. Any pointers is very much appreciated...

Comment: Adding some more info. Hope it will be helpful for some one. The code is working fine now (this morning). Not sure what is wrong or correct. This same code gave me issue yesterday evening. I am observing this pattern for a long time. Works incorrectly and after some time works correctly. Same code behaving differently at different times. Not sure why.  Can I move this to production? Mongo Experts, please help. Thanks

Comment: What type is messageid (is that even the correct case) in mongo?  regexes only work against strings.

Comment: Any particular reason to use a regex match for an id ? what happens if you just use query = new BasicDbObject("_id": messageId)